# (In C) Implementing stack using an array - Run-time error when doubling array size

Tags: c, arrays, stack, double, runtime-error

When my array is full, I double it using realloc() in my doublestack() function. Doing this more than twice gives me a run-time error.
I figured it might be because the size of the original stack(which was created using the create() function) is still the same, so I doubled that too, and the run-time error was eliminated.

My questions:

1. Is this what is actually going on? The stack needs to be doubled every time the array is doubled?
2. If it is, why was the original stack able to support the first and second calls to doublestack() in the first place?
3. Could you possibly give me a graphical/memory map explanation of what exactly is going on when we realloc() the array and stack?
4. Am I wasting any memory? Is there a better way to implement a stack using an array?

Thanks a bunch for your time.

CODE and OUTPUTS:(Uncomment where it says UNCOMMENT to double stack size using realloc())

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INIT_CAPACITY 1

struct stack
{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    int *array;
};

struct stack * create(int);
void push(struct stack *,int);
int top(struct stack *);
int isfull(struct stack *);
int isempty(struct stack *);
void traverse(struct stack *);
struct stack *doublestack(struct stack *);
int pop(struct stack *);

int main()
{
    struct stack *S=create(INIT_CAPACITY);
    push(S,1);
    push(S,2);//First call to doublestack()
    push(S,3);//Second call to doublestack()
    push(S,4);
    push(S,5);//Third call to doublestack() - ERROR
    traverse(S);
}

struct stack * create(int capacity)//create a new stack with INIT_CAPACITY
{
    struct stack *newstack=(struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    if(!newstack)   return NULL;
    newstack->top=-1;
    newstack->capacity=capacity;
    newstack->array=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(newstack->capacity));
    return newstack;

}

void push(struct stack *s,int data)
{
    printf("\nCurrent stack is");
    traverse(s);
    printf("\nPushing %d onto stack:\n\n",data);
    if(isfull(s))
    {
        printf("\nStack is FULL.Now doubling...\n\n");
        doublestack(s);
    }
    (s->top)++;
    s->array[s->top]=data;
}

struct stack * doublestack(struct stack *s)//using realloc()
{
    s=realloc(s,(sizeof(struct stack)*2));//**UNCOMMENT THIS TO ELIMINATE ERROR**
    s->capacity *= 2;
    s->array=realloc(s->array,s->capacity);
}

void traverse(struct stack *s)
{
    printf("\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i <= s->top;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",s->array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int top(struct stack *s)
{
    return s->array[s->top];
}

int isfull(struct stack *s)
{
    return (s->capacity)-1==s->top;
}

int isempty(struct stack *s)
{
    return s->top==-1;
}

int pop(struct stack *s)
{
    if(isempty(s))
    {
        printf("\nStack is EMPTY\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int data=s->array[s->top];
    s->top--;
    return data;
}
```

OUTPUT 1:(with no doubling of stack, and thus with run-time error)

```
Current stack is

Pushing 1 onto stack:

Current stack is
1   

Pushing 2 onto stack:

Stack is FULL.Now doubling...

Current stack is
1   2   

Pushing 3 onto stack:

Stack is FULL.Now doubling...

Current stack is
1   2   3   

Pushing 4 onto stack:

Current stack is
1   2   3   4   

Pushing 5 onto stack:

Stack is FULL.Now doubling...

*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x09191018 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x70f01)[0xb75e5f01]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x7660d)[0xb75eb60d]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(realloc+0xdd)[0xb75eb8ed]
./a.out[0x8048674]
./a.out[0x804861c]
./a.out[0x8048569]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb758be46]
./a.out[0x8048421]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 549947     /home/user/a.out
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00000000 08:07 549947     /home/user/a.out
09191000-091b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7400000-b7421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7421000-b7500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7546000-b7562000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 548        /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7562000-b7563000 rw-p 0001b000 08:07 548        /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7574000-b7575000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7575000-b76d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 468        /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.13.so
b76d1000-b76d2000 ---p 0015c000 08:07 468        /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.13.so
b76d2000-b76d4000 r--p 0015c000 08:07 468        /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.13.so
b76d4000-b76d5000 rw-p 0015e000 08:07 468        /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.13.so
b76d5000-b76d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76e8000-b76eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76eb000-b76ec000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b76ec000-b7708000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 504        /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
b7708000-b7709000 r--p 0001b000 08:07 504        /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
b7709000-b770a000 rw-p 0001c000 08:07 504        /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
bfb34000-bfb55000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

OUTPUT 2:(with doubling of stack and no errors)

```
Current stack is

Pushing 1 onto stack:

Current stack is
1   

Pushing 2 onto stack:

Stack is FULL.Now doubling...

Current stack is
1   2   

Pushing 3 onto stack:

Current stack is
1   2   3   

Pushing 4 onto stack:

Current stack is
1   2   3   4   

Pushing 5 onto stack:

1   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: You should probably tag this with `c`.

Comment: It's either `s->top = s->top + 1` or `(s->top)++` (parens optional).  Not `s->top=s->top++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s->capacity` stores the number of items in your stack.  Each item has the size of `sizeof(int)`.  The 2nd arg to realloc is the number of **bytes**, just like `malloc`.

```
s->array=realloc(s->array,s->capacity);
```

You want

```
s->array=realloc(s->array, s->capacity * sizeof(int));
```

Or more generically

```
s->array = realloc(s->array, s->capacity * sizeof(*(s->array)));
```

Also, you should check the return value of `realloc` and handle any errors that occur.

This code is nonsense:

```
s=realloc(s,(sizeof(struct stack)*2));//**UNCOMMENT THIS TO ELIMINATE ERROR**
```

First, if `realloc` decides to move your array, you aren't returning the new `s` to the caller.  But more importantly, you need to resize the array, not the metadata surrounding it.  It's just coincidence that uncommenting that line hides the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might be overwriting your buffer somewhere ... and corrupting the heap.

Check the code where you're writing to your "stack".

Also: consider using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html).

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, my compiler reports two warnings:

```
foo.c:40:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
foo.c:61:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

#### The first one:

In `create()` you never actually return the new stack. Which means that you will shortly do some undefined behavior.

#### The second one:

In `doublestack()` you never return anything, but you also never try to use the (missed) return value. But, if the realloc succeeds, then the previous pointer is possibly an invalid pointer now, which would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Returning the new stack from create() - Fixed and edited. But the same run-time error is still there unless I double the stack..

Comment: This is correct, if your S stack pointer is pointing to what is returned by create then you have no idea where it is pointing since create doesn't return the stack pointer. Since you never reassign S it works for a while but it would likely not be consistent. Remember, when you pass a pointer into a function like you do with create and doublestack, you are simply copying the number representing the memory location into the function, you are not actually doing anything to the pointer that you passed in.

Comment: Returning the doubled stack from doublestack() - I tried returning the doubled stack back to s, but still got the same error. Is returning the doubled stack to the original stack a problem? Will I need to create a new stack altogether in push()? My change in my doublestack() function was: adding this last line - "return s;". My change in my push() function was: in the if() construct, changing the line "doublestack(s);" to "s=doublestack(s);"